# Scala implicit conversions with multiple arguments

Tags: scala, implicit

I've always thought that Scala implicit conversions could only take one argument, and if you needed something like conversion from multiple arguments, you would use a tuple. However, I was surprised to find that Scala 2.10.3 actually accepts this (silly) definition without problem:

```
scala> implicit def foo(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i
foo: (i: Int, j: Int)Int
```

Is there any way or reason to use such a multi-argument implicit?

Comment: You could use it like this: `def bar[A, B, C](a: A, b: B)(implicit f: (A, B) => C) = f(a, b)`, though I don't think it's useful.

Comment: For the record, amazing how @retronym covers the bases.  Is there more than one retronym?  Is it a retronym collective?

Comment: @som-snytt: In a manner of speaking... At least one of them is Tyler Durden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `implicit` functions are conversions!

Any implicit function with a single argument *could* be used as a conversion, but that's not the only use-case for implicits.

Functions are just another type and, as such, you can specify an implicit argument as in `(implicit fn: (Int, Int) => Int)`

I wouldn't do this though, anything you intend to pass as an implicit should have a *far* more specific type that better self-documents its intended purpose.